# Keep text aligned when it wraps below floated element?

Tags: html, css

Im making a responsive site but ive made my container div in the example a fixed width to illustrate the issue.

When the text wraps onto multiple lines and extends below the green box it loses its indention. Can I fix this with CSS only, not altering the HTML?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IHsBj

```
<div class="cont">
<label for="one">
  <div class="">
    <a href="#" class="check-style">
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" id="one" name="privacy"></div> Ive read <a href="#">document</a>. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. And I agree. 
</label>
</div>

.cont {
  width: 400px;  
}

.check-style {
  background: green;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the way Bootstrap does it with their media objects. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media

Comment: You should consider altering the HTML though, as it's [not valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element): a `label` element may only contain CDATA and inline elements without label -> no `div` allowed:

Comment: This is a short term fix and needs to be CSS only at this stage.

Comment: Should do something like this [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/HyGF5/)

Comment: @jdln just give margin { margin: 0 20px 100% 0; }

Comment: Rudy, please post your post as an answer so it can be accepted as the answer...

Comment: @jdln by giving margin, it should work.
any issue.. ?

Comment: @aslan that will affect content below it.

Comment: @Ruddy I cant change the HTML.

Comment: @jdln Your HTML is invalid. I would recommend changing it before moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Not nice, but working .. add/change your css to the following:

```
.cont {
  width: 400px;  
}

label > div {
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.check-style {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

See it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fpkAI)

The Problem with that solution is the absolute height for the div

Comment: The last word "agree. " is still wrapping.